# Git: Best way to add only some parts of a file from another branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-checkout

Let's say you have a branch `master` and another branch `production`, both containing a version of the file `prog.py`, as well as many other files.  Imagine that you modify many files in the production branch, including `prog.py`.  Now, what is the best way of having only *some* changes made on `prog.py` in the `production` branch be applied to its version in the `master` branch?

I started moving to the `master` branch and importing the file from the `production` branch:

```
git checkout master
git checkout production -- prog.py
```

because I was hoping to be able to do `git add -p` and select the changes by hand.  The problem is that `prog.py` is both in the working tree and in the index.  How can I remove it from the index without touching the working tree?

Or is there a better way of choosing which changes in `prog.py` should be imported from the `production` branch into the `master` branch?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was true when this question was asked, but with a current version of git you can do the following:

```
git checkout -p production -- prog.py
```

and you'll get the same interactive hunk-picker you do for most `-p` commands.

Comment: Thanks!  I changed the accepted answer from mine to yours, as your is a more efficient method.

Answer (score 4):

Making small and granular commits that only do one thing, and then later cherry-picking the changes you also want in the other branch using `git cherry-pick $commit_id` would seem like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thanks.  Does cherry-pick allow you to cherry pick changes *within* a single file?

Comment: It cherry-picks commits, which you can certainly modify later if it turns out you didn't do your commits as granular as you might've wanted to.  eg. `git reset HEAD~1`, and `git add -p`, and `git commit -c $commit_id`,

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I just tried `git reset`, and it did remove the changes stored in the index.  `git add -p` then works as expected, allowing one to choose the individual changes that should be applied (i.e. stored in the index).  The non-wanted changes can then be discarded with `git commit`, and then `git reset --hard`.

Hopefully the question and this answer will be of interest to someone else! :)

PS: I marked this answer as the accepted one because it does check out a *single* file, as asked in the original question.